# In Agile project management, do you keep everything in Jira or maintain some documents?

Tags: scrum, agile, kanban, project-management-style, risk-management

I'd like to know about agile project management practices - do you keep everything in Jira or do you create and maintain any external documents (Requirements, Project schedule, Definition of done, Risks registry, etc)?

(I assume that a project isn't simple, short-term one.)

Comment: JIRA is a ticketing system. What's the actual use case or problem you're trying to address?

Comment: Hi Chris, as your question stands, it's too open and doesn't state an actual problem, so it's the kind of [dont-ask](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) question. Please reformulate it stating a problem you noticed by trying to keep everything on jira (or by having the info scattered in different systems, for the matter)... and then we'll be able to help you further. I'll wait a bit longer for community input (i.e. close votes) before closing this as off-topic.

Comment: Classic misconception: https://dilbert.com/strip/2007-11-26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of most Agile development, the details of a given piece of functionality can change over time (in fact, if this isn't true, you aren't very agile). Therefor, what is on a given card in your backlog is just a description of that point in time, making it ill-suited for long-term documentation. Further, documenting too much in cards can lead to a large amount of difficultly finding information later, even if it hasn't changed.

My suggestion is to never look to cards as documentation. If you need to create documentation, create it in a place more suited for your needs. It is also worth noting that while things like Sharepoint and Confluence or even traditional documentation systems can be helpful, many Agile teams turn to more purpose-build documentation that is more effective. For example, if I want to know how an API works, I'd rather have that in an executable test so that I can see how it works, try variations, and be alerted if the application drifts from expectations. If I want to document style guides, a system like Zeplin bridges the gap between design apps and code.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully kept the "issues" in Jira and then used Confluence for the type of documents that you are mentioning. My recommendation would be to keep your documents in a more appropriate system, for instance Confluence.

Sure any kind of documentation system would do. Both Jira and Confluence are from the same provider, Atlassian.

Harry